How to use cuSOLVER Multi-GPU to get eigenvalues with CuPy
I have a large, dense, symmetric matrix (~50000x50000) that I want to calcuate the eigenvalues of.
I tried cupy.linalg.eigvalsh(), but ran out of memory on a single GPU. I know the cuSOLVER library also has a Multi-GPU (same node) version that can calculate eigenvalues with a multi-GPU setup. Is there an option to use this in CuPy? Otherwise, what are my alternatives?
